# How to create a trigger in oracle to prevent overlapping date ranges

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-11g, date

I'm learning Oracle and I had a problem.

Chat table:

```
CREATE TABLE training
(
   id_training      NUMBER,
   id_user          NUMBER,
   start_training   DATE,
   end_training     DATE
);
```

I want to insert the same `id_user` with another `start_training` and `end_training` dates. I have to create a trigger just to ensure that the dates will not be located between any previously registered `start_training` and `end_training` dates.

I was thinking of using `:old` and `:new` in the trigger, but if I use an `insert` in my trigger the data of `:old` always will be `null`.

How can I overcome this problem of changing `:old` values, if I'm inserting new values inside my trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch. I get an error from the trigger on db<>fiddle, but you shpould be able to use the idea. First I'll add some constraints on the table, this will simplify things a lot:

```
CREATE TABLE training
( id_user          NUMBER NOT NULL
, start_training   DATE NOT NULL
, end_training     DATE
,     constraint ak1_training unique (id_user, start_training)
,     constraint c1_training check (start_training <= end_training)
);
```

I assume `id_training` is some sort of auto increment number so I left that out since it is not relevant for the idea. Comments:

- All attributes except end_training is not null
- is_user and start_training is unique
- start_training is before or equal to end_training. The constraint is satisfied if end_training is null.

.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER training_validation
BEFORE INSERT ON training
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (
           select 1 from training t
                 where t.id_user = new.user
             and (t.start_training between new.start_training and coalesce(new.end_training, current_date))
                or
                  coalesce(t.start_end, current_date) between new.start_training and coalesce(new.end_training, current_date))
     ) 

  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Some msg ...' );
  END IF;
END training_validation;
```

I get the error:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

FWIW, I get the same error with the trivial examples I found googling around

Anyhow, the idea is to throw an error if there exists a previous start_training between the new.start_training and new.end_training. Since the new.end_training is typically null, we map that to current_date via coalesce. In the same manner, we check for the previous start_training.

Note that if start_training is not null, we won't have to take possible nulls in consideration. Also since we know that:

```
start_training <= end_training
```

we can rely on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you *could* change the .old and/or .new values in the trigger, what would you change them *to*?

Presumably the User will have chosen a training event to attend based on their availability.  Having the database "magically" change it to some other event when they hit "Save" doesn't make for a User-Friendly experience.

I would argue the best you could do would be to raise an error, throw out the whole transaction and let them pick another event.